# How to make text visible in Plain Text after changing its size?

Tags: java, android, plaintext, hint

I have problem with changing size of plain text in Android Studio. 
This is default size of window, and it looks perfect.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="588dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="#F8F8F8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But after changing these values `android:layout_width="196dp"` &  `android:layout_height="32dp"` top of hint is cut in half. Like on this [screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyZOt.png). Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but after adding background `android:background="#000000"` it's looking perfect. So it's solution

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `android:layout_height="32dp"`, it is too small for the standard text size.
So, converting to `android:layout_height="wrapcontent"` is the ideal solution.

If you really have to stick to height of 32dp , you should decrease the text size so that it can fit in the given 32dp height.

like that `android:textSize="10dp"`